# Built a Calculator but don’t know why I won’t get my answer returned to me?

Tags: python, math, project

## Operations

**Addition**

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**Subtraction**

```
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y
```

**Multiplication**

```
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
```

**Division**

```
def divide(x, y):
    return x /y
```

## Main

```
print("Choose your math path!")
print("1.Add  +")
print("2.Subtract - ")
print("3.Multiply  *")
print("4.Divison /") 

calculate = int(input("Addition through division - 1/ 2/ 3/ 4:"))

num = int(input("Enter first number here please:"))

num2 = int(input("Enter second number here please:"))
```

**I would think that if calculate == 1 wouldn’t it print and add my numbers?**

```
if calculate == “1”:
    print(num, num2,add(num, num2))
elif calculate == "2":
    print(num, num2, subtract(num, num2))
elif calculate == "3":
    print(num, num2, multiply(num, num2))
elif calculate == "4":
    print(num, num2, divide(num, num2))
else:
    print("Wrong choice give it another go!")
```

Comment: The formatting make this difficult to follow, can you edit it?

Answer (score 1):

`calculate` is an `int`, but you are checking if it equals a `str`. An `int` (short for integer) is a number, and a `str` (short for string) is a piece of text with quotes around it.

The `input()` function returns a `str`.
That means that if you use `x = input()` and the user enters `1`, `x` will be set to `'1'` (a `str`), not `1`, (an `int`).

```
>>> x = input('Enter a number: ')
Enter a number: 1
>>> x
'1'
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
```

The `int()` function returns an `int`.
If you pass a `str` into the `int()` function, it will attempt to convert it to an `int` and return it.

```
>>> x = '1'
>>> x
'1'
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> int(x)
1
>>> type(int(x))
<class 'int'>
```

If you want to get an `int` from the user, you can use `int(input())`.
`input()` gets a `str` from the user, and `int()` converts it to an `int`.

```
>>> x = int(input('Enter a number: ')
Enter a number: 5
>>> x
5
```

A `str` cannot be equal to an `int` because they are two completely different types. To a computer, `1` isn't the same thing as `'1'`, just like `12` isn't the same thing as `'abc'`.

By using `int(input)`, you are setting `calculate` equal to an `int`:

```
calculate = int(input("Addition through division - 1/ 2/ 3/ 4:"))
```

When checking what `calculate` equals, however, you are comparing it to a `str`. Remember: a `str` is a piece of text with quotes around it.

This checks if `calculate` is a piece of text (a `str`) that says `'1'`:

```
if calculate == '1':
```

This checks if `calculate` is a number (an `int`) that is `1`:

```
if calculate == 1:
```

Because you are setting `calculate` to an `int` (by using `int(input())`), only the second form will work correctly.

Comment: Can you go in depth into this so I could understand it very clearly.

Comment: @Ralph I went back and added a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much.